# Java to C++ UTC time - finding the Utc Zone Time Offset in seconds

Tags: c++, utc, c++-chrono

I need to serialize a UTC date time instance from java to c++ using the minimal length of pure ByteBuffer of unsigned chars.
I need the time point with to be able to support minimum nanoseconds precision.

From the java side i have looked in the classes ZonedDateTime and OffsetDateTime and seen what kind of primitive they are using to store the time and all together this is equal to 17 bytes which is kind of a lot.

Please note that i am here not transferring the zone itself since i have not found a way to map those  zone strings from IANA to integers. Thus i guess the zone offset will be enough. Since bought sides will have to convert their time point to a particular offset before sending it to the server lets say that will be UTC 0.   I am looking for a solution that is queering the local time i.e. no NTP servers involved!

the java side looks like this:

```
        // 4 byte
        Integer year = offsetDateTime.getYear();
        // 1 byte           
        Integer month = offsetDateTime.getMonthValue();
        // 1 byte
        Integer day = offsetDateTime.getDayOfMonth();
        // 1 byte
        Integer hour = offsetDateTime.getHour();
        // 1 byte
        Integer minutes = offsetDateTime.getMinute();
        // 1 byte
        Integer seconds = offsetDateTime.getSecond();
        // 4 byte
        Integer nanoSeconds = offsetDateTime.getNano();
        // 4 byte
        Integer utcZoneTimeTotalSecondsOffset = offsetDateTime.getOffset().getTotalSeconds();
```

on the c++ side i need to do the same as well as to be able to construct a time point from all those integers above.
I have found how to get the the above information except the utcOffset i.e. the last integer.

i would like to use chrono to consume this buffer and instantiate a time point from it. however i am not able to find a way to to get the time offset in c++. How do i get the time offset with chrono and then construct a time point from the above information?

```
auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
time_t itt = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now);

tm utc_tm = *gmtime(&itt);

std::cout << utc_tm.tm_year + 1900 << '-';
std::cout << utc_tm.tm_mon + 1 << '-';
std::cout << utc_tm.tm_mday << ' ';
std::cout << utc_tm.tm_hour << ':';
std::cout << utc_tm.tm_min << ':';
std::cout << utc_tm.tm_sec << '\n';

? wher is the time zoneOffset here ?
```

if i use

```
 utc_tm.tm_gmtoff
```

this is giving me the wrong information . at least in my case. So i believe gmtoff is not the way to go , but if gmtoff is not the way then what is?

Comment: It looks like in C++ we don't have time zone. Until C++20 used time zone is implementation specific, after it looks like it should be UTC.

Comment: In C++ is the final product a UTC time point, or a local time point?

Comment: @HowardHinnant many thanks for your replay, i have watched 3 of your videos on the c++ con  about the TZ library. Since you are the person that is involved in the TZ library can you advise what kind of primitives shell we use during the serialization  now in order to transfer time from java to c++, i mean for example the seconds in cpp is long long as you have said it yourself but in my example i am using 1 byte for a seconds and 4 bytes for nanoseconds, what would be the minimum size required to transfer UTC time point in c++ in c++20?

Comment: @sklott thanks for the feedback, that is a big problem when you want to compare a time in a different time zones. I am search for a code that will have to work in webassembly as well. I did not expected this.

Comment: One can express a UTC time point with nanoseconds precision in C++ using a total of 8 bytes, as long as the time point is approximately in the range of years 1678 to 2262.  If one needs time zones or UTC offsets, that is going to require more storage.

Comment: @HowardHinnant thanks for the feedback, is there any example somewhere with the minimum space required with TimeZones and UTC offfsets? I was going trough https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/wiki/Examples-and-Recipes#elsetime but there you always supply the time zone such as auto zt = make_zoned(tz_name, tp);  i.e. i am trying to understand how many bytes are required for that in c++20, and how to initialize the chrono time instance from all separate parts. Do you know if there is any example for that?

Comment: What is “percition”?

Comment: precision,, sorry English is not my mother language

Comment: What *exactly* is your goal? Communicate a moment in UTC with a resolution of nanoseconds in a minimum of octets to be read in C++? Why nanoseconds, do you understand that conventional computer clock hardware is not accurate to nanoseconds? If you want UTC, why do you keep talking about offsets and zones? Is the minimum number of octets really critical? The recommended way to exchange date-time values is through text in standard [ISO 8601 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Comment: Why deal with the offset? Just create either OffsetDateTime or ZonedDateTime with UTC ZoneId.

Comment: @BasilBourque ,  the reason i talk about Offsets and Zones is becuase  need to be able to compare time between clients and server, and since those can be in a different time zones, when comparing the time moments and logging those on the server you need to know the exact zone and offset from the client in order to be able to later compare the logs with the server, taking into accounts that there are multiple servers worldwide. And yes i do understand that the conventional computer clock is not accurate and does not support nanoseconds.

Comment: If all clients/servers always communicate with each other in UTC, then it becomes very easy to compare time stamps.  Unless of course for some reason one has to know things like whether a time stamp was during open/closed local times of a client/server.

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer, but here is one way one might serialize a C++ local time point using [Howard Hinnant's free, open source time zone library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date).

```
#include "date/tz.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

std::string
to_string(date::zoned_time<std::chrono::nanoseconds> t)
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace date;
    ostringstream out;
    out << t.get_sys_time().time_since_epoch().count()
        << ' ' << t.get_time_zone()->name();
    return out.str();
}

date::zoned_time<std::chrono::nanoseconds>
from_string(const std::string& s)
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    using namespace date;
    istringstream in{s};
    long long ns;
    std::string tz_name;
    in >> ns >> tz_name;
    return {tz_name, sys_time<nanoseconds>{nanoseconds{ns}}};
}

int
main()
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    using namespace date;
    zoned_time<nanoseconds> zt{current_zone(), system_clock::now()};
    cout << zt << '\n';
    auto s = to_string(zt);
    cout << s << '\n';
    zt = from_string(s);
    cout << zt << '\n';
}
```

I'm using a `std::string` to represent the serialization, which one might send across a network.

This example begins in `main` with creating a nanosecond-precision local time point, stored in `date::zoned_time<nanoseconds>`, using the computer's current local time zone, and the current UTC time.  `main` first simply prints this time stamp out, which for me just output:

```
2019-09-11 12:37:04.846272000 EDT
```

which is my current local date/time and time zone abbreviation.

Next the program converts this to a string with a small (but not necessarily minimal) number of ASCII characters to completely describe the local time point.  I've chosen the format:

```
<Number of nanoseconds since epoch> <IANA time zone name>
```

In this example, that string is:

```
1568219824846272000 America/New_York
```

This `string` is formed in `to_string`, which simply streams out the "time since epoch" of the system time, of the `zoned_time`.  Then adds a space, and streams out the name of the time zone.

`from_string` reverses this operation by reading in the number of nanoseconds, and then reading in the time zone name.  It then forms a `zoned_time<nanoseconds>` by pairing the time zone name, and forming a `sys_time<nanoseconds>` with the integer that was parsed.

`main` prints out the parsed `zoned_time` to ensure we have a loss-less round trip:

```
2019-09-11 12:37:04.846272000 EDT
```

In order to get a loss-less conversion that includes local time, one really needs to transmit the IANA time zone name, not just the current UTC offset.  With only the UTC offset, one can recover the exact UTC time point.  But one can not perform any local time arithmetic, or comparison with other local time points because one can not know the rules for when one changes the UTC offset.  Only with the full IANA time zone name can one pass the information along about those rules.

Comment: Howard,  many thanks for the reply  couple of additional thing, Do you know if there is a way to map the string of the zone "America/New_York"  to an integer? I am trying to avoid the string representation for serialization and use instead a fixed length integers for that reason.  Since i would like to have the same DTO for java and C++ as an structure to use in order to exchange information. One more question is do you know if "date/tz.h" has been tested with Webassembly before?

Comment: There is no official name<->integer mapping.  However you could create your own.  There are currently 593 names associated with time zones.  Some of these names actually refer to the same zone, but most OS's treat them as distinct copies of zones.

Comment: I am not aware of any use of tz.h with Webassembly.